# vectorizing a non-trivial function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array, with shape `(100,3)`

```
a = np.random((100,3))
```

and I want to call a function `fun`:

```
b = fun(a)
```

This function is currently defined:

```
@np.vectorize
def fun(r):
  if r <= 0.0: return 0.0
  else:        return min(2.0/(1.0 + r), 2.0*r/(1.0 + r))
```

and this works fun. But I would like to express this in a more numpythonic (and therefore more efficient) way. I tried:

```
def fun(r):
  ans = zeros_like(r)
  ans[r > 0.0] = min(2.0/(1.0 + r), 2.0*r/(1.0 + r))
  return ans
```

but that don't work as the `min` is not doing what I want. I also tried:

```
def fun(r):
  return np.piecewise(r
                     , [r <= 0.0, r > 0.0]
                     , [0.0, lambda x: min(2.0/(1.0 + x), 2.0*x/(1.0 + x))]
                     )
```

but that doesn't work for a similar reason. So how should I do it?

Comment: There's a difference between `min`, `np.min` and `np.minimum`. In this case, it looks like you want `np.minimum`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `np.min` would find the min of the whole array, which is the incorrect behaviour. `np.minimum` might be the correct one to use, but it says `ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape`.

Comment: `np.minimum(2./(1.+r),2.*r/(1.+r))` works for me; the problem is with the assignment: `ans[r>0]` returns all entries where r is nonzero as an 1d array. How about `(r>0)*np.minimum(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both @clipper and @christianclason, I figured out something that works:

```
def fun(r):
  np.clip(r, 0.0, r, out=r)
  return 2.0 * np.minimum(1.0, r) / (1.0 + r)
```

and my program gets about a 20% reduction in total run time! Unfortunately, the code now looks 20% more rubbish.

Comment: Define "rubbish".

Comment: Your call to `np.clip` modifies the array `r`, which is passed by reference; hence, if you call `fun(a)`, the array `a` will remain clipped afterward in the calling function (and not just inside `fun`).

Comment: more rubbish: less like mathematics, less like fortran

Answer (score 6):

```
    def f(r):
        return 2 * np.clip(r, 0, 1) / (r + 1)
```

Comment: clipper, Welcome to SciComp.  Usually when answering it is useful to explain your answer.  Even if the code is correct, if the asker doesn't understand it, it may not help them.

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory.